# How do I remove a line if it begins with a . or a > using sed?

Tags: shell-script, sed, regular-expression

For the life of me I can't get this to work properly (forgive me if this is a trivial question).

I have a text file that have lines that begin with either a period, ".", or a right arrow, ">". I need to remove such lines.

So far, I have the following one liner using `sed`:

```
sed '/^\./ d' < inputFile.text > outputFile.txt
```

which successfully removes the lines beginning with a period. How can I also include the right arrow in this regular expression so that lines that begin with them are also removed?

I'm using OS X.

Comment: `sed '/\(^\.\|^>\)/d' file`

Comment: @jasonwryan: It's too complex and not portable, why don't make it easier with standard one?

Comment: @cuonglm because I'm not mikeserv: I know next to nothing about sed :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use multiple scripts:

```
sed -e '/^\./d' -e '/^>/d' <file
```

or using characters class:

```
sed -e '/^[.>]/d' <file
```